# Google play submission process: can we add custom art in screenshots?

Tags: android, google-play, submission

I have tried to find the answer to this question online without success.
The official doc from Google says: "

> Screenshots (Required): We require 2 screenshots. Use: Displayed on
>   the details page for your application in Google Play. You may upload
>   up to 8 screenshots. Specs: 320w x 480h, 480w x 800h, or 480w x 854h;
>   24 bit PNG or JPEG (no alpha) Full bleed, no border in art. Tips:
>   Landscape thumbnails are cropped, but we preserve the image’s full
>   size and aspect ratio if the user opens it up on Google Play app.

To me this is unclear if we can edit the screenshots to add custom art such as add marketing messages for example, or is it forbidden?

Thanks

Comment: Now that's a technical problem.

Comment: Sorry didn't know only 100% technical questions were allowed on this site. could you point me to the official documentation specifying this please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's okay, a lot of popular game do this, see [Cut The Rope](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.zeptolab.ctr.paid) or even [Angry Birds](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.rovio.angrybirdsspace.premium).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it is useful to have actual examples too

Comment: I don't think angry bird is still doing it

Answer (score 0):

I believe with custom art you mean some banner on top of app's screenshot with some text. I think that should be fine as long as you are within the image size ratio. Apple App store which probably have a greater scrutiny allows these types of screenshots. You should be good here.